Trace the class-subclass in the ontology
I would like to write a sparql query that starts from a childlessclass, then traces its parent class, and the parent class of the parent class and so on.
Basically:

A is a subclass of B
B is a subclass of C
C is a subclass of D
C is a subclass of E
D is a subclass of F
and so on.
can some one help me with this?

I tried to order by depth:
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
PREFIX onto: <http://www.ontotext.com/>
SELECT ?childClass ?childLabel ?parentClass ?parentLabel (COUNT(?intermediate) AS ?depth)

WHERE {
  ?childClass skos:prefLabel "LR20"@en .

  ?childClass rdfs:subClassOf* ?parentClass .

  FILTER(isIRI(?parentClass))

  OPTIONAL { ?childClass skos:prefLabel ?childLabel . }
  OPTIONAL { ?parentClass skos:prefLabel ?parentLabel . }
  OPTIONAL { ?childClass rdfs:subClassOf ?intermediate . ?intermediate rdfs:subClassOf* ?parentClass . }
}
GROUP BY ?childClass ?childLabel ?parentClass ?parentLabel
ORDER BY ?depth

This is a problem cos I am unsure whose parentclass it from just the depth.
